# Ubuntu EC2 - Run Python script on reboot

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, startup

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 EC2 Instance and I need to run a python script every time the instance is Started.
I tried everything suggested on every question in the forum and haven't had any luck yet.

Specifically I've tested:

- Adding `@reboot python3 /home/project/script.py` to crontab
- Adding `@reboot /bin/startup.sh` and having the bash file configured to run the `/home/project/script.py`
- Using `etc/rc.local`, `etc/init/mystartup.conf`, `etc/systemd/mystartup.conf`
- Passing User Data

Probably missing a few others and literally nothing worked even though running the script manually works wonders.

Thanks a lot in advance for the help!

Comment: I don't know if this ec2 has systemd, but if it has then it should be simple to create a service file that executes your script on startup.

Answer (score 0):

Put the script into: `/var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot/`

Cloud-Init, which runs User Data, will also check this directory.

From [Modules — cloud-init documentation](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html?highlight=per-boot#scripts-per-boot):

> Any scripts in the `scripts/per-boot` directory on the datasource will be run every time the system boots. Scripts will be run in alphabetical order.